# localhost doesn't execute php files after update to Maverick/Yosemite OS

Tags: php, apache, osx-mavericks

So I've upgraded to Mavericks (or maybe Yosemite) yesterday but now I only get a view of my directory when I visit localhost but the included index.php isn't executed anymore.

I have to uncommented the virtualhosts line in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

so my virtual hosts work but php doesn't get executed.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Found the solution:

Have to uncomment this line in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` as well:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Don't forget to restart Apache after changes:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Answer (score 20):

This did the trick for me:

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/httpd.conf.pre-update /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Basically restores your previous config. Not sure why this doesnt happen by default - But o well.

**UPDATE:** Same for the php.ini file:

```
sudo cp /etc/php.ini-5.2-previous /etc/php.ini
```

Comment: Thanks.. had to do something similar for my php.ini config.. see update.

Comment: This solved my 403 Forbidden problem after updating to Mavericks. Thanks!

Comment: For me it the name for the previous httpd.conf file was different:
`sudo cp /etc/apache2/httpd.conf~previous /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`