# localhost downloading the *.php files instead of viewing it

Tags: php, apache

I have upgraded from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.5 (Im running Ubuntu 12.04) By removing the PHP and re-install the 5.5 version and everything worked fine during the installation,
now when i open my localhost and try to open any website on my localhost it doesn't execute index.php but it download the index.php as a text file.
i restarted Apache2 and saw this posts

[nginx localhost is downloading php files in browser, instead of serving them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149934/nginx-localhost-is-downloading-php-files-in-browser-instead-of-serving-them)
and [localhost doesn't execute php files after update to Maverick/Yosemite OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584893/localhost-doesnt-execute-php-files-after-update-to-maverick-os) but it doesn't help.

Help would be appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like this is probably worth a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page It sounds like Apache either doesn't have a PHP module enabled, or you've not instructed it to process .php files as PHP files.

Comment: Is there any chance you are using old browser? never tried this, but it is hillarious. https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=129871

Comment: How did you uninstall/reinstall PHP? Did you use `apt-get` or any other manual process?

Comment: no im not using old browser, i did uninstall using purge and installed using sudo apt-get install php5

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding this to your conf or htaccess:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

or do a proper installation.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu

Comment: A better way would be to stick with Ubuntu's own way of adding modules. This would introduce trouble in the future...

Comment: re-installation didnt work too . same problem exists

Answer (score 1):

Try using different browser for opening php files. It was not working for me when I opened php files using Chrome. But the same worked in Firefox browser.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should take a look at your php module in your apache2. As far as i know php runs as a module in apache so search your httpd.conf for loaded modules and look at your /var/log/apache/error.log or where ever your apache error log

Comment: my httpd.conf file is empty

Answer (score 0):

php is not correctly installed on your server otherwise it would have not downloaded the php file. On Ubuntu terminal try

```
php -v
```

under your

```
/etc/apche2/mods-enabled
```

see if you have php5.load in the current directory.

Comment: You should be able to install any missing module with `sudo a2enmod missingmodule`

Comment: PHP 5.5.16-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli) (built: Aug 25 2014 10:23:59) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP ....

and i dont have php5.load file in that directory

Comment: which guide did you follow to install LAMP ?

Comment: http://www.dev-metal.com/how-to-setup-latest-version-of-php-5-5-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

Comment: this installed php 5.3 not php 5.5